# Clone an existing ApplicationContext in Spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have a multi-threaded application I am trying to write with Spring, right now I am using the new **thread** scope declaration on my beans and passing the same context into the **Runnable** class. The threading works fine and I get a new copy of the DAO/Services for each thread so exactly how I want it.

Though I think I'll have memory issues in this case since these threads can spawn indefinitely, but creating a brand new **ApplicationContext** with **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext** is slow, is there a way to make a deep copy of the context so it doesn't need to be reloaded from scratch?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you think you can't share your context.

Comment: I have a single thread that polls and runs in a "scheduleWithFixedDelay" which never stops, therefore this context is never closed. This thread spawns worker threads to do processing, at the moment I am passing in the same context, but I am worried that since I don't call .close() on the context after these threads run, that it'll eat up all my memory. So ideally I'd create a new context, get my Runnable bean, run it, then close the context. Which I am doing but every time I create a context it's slow, wish there was a way to clone it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using thread scope beans, use [singleton scope beans](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton). This is the default behavior, so you shouldn't have to do anything special -- i.e. don't specify a scope. If you've already added a custom thread scope, then simply remove that part of your config.

There should be no need to close a context containing singleton scope beans until application shutdown. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-shutdown) is how to do a clean shutdown.

The whole ideal of cloning an `ApplicationContext` is a step in the wrong direction. You really ought to think only in terms of the lifecycle of the Spring-managed beans. In other words, generally your application should not know or care about the `ApplicationContext`, but rather should just rely on the Spring IoC working properly. So, your original question changes from "how do I create a new `ApplicationContext`?" to "how do I get references to the right Spring-managed beans"? Further, if you clone the `ApplicationContext`, then you probably break the contract of Spring's IoC container (e.g. create multiple instances of a database connection pool which ought to be a singleton), and nobody else will be able to figure out what's going on!

Comment: Good point, vote+, in my case I am creating a new context, so singleton works fine, I only needed the thread scope earlier because I was reusing a single context. But that still leaves the issue, is there a faster way to clone an existing context, rather than reinitializing it through new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext?

Comment: I updated my response to address this question. Basically you shouldn't be trying to do this, and I have tried to motivate why.

Comment: Ah thanks, I'm not using a connection pool that's what confused me, I was trying to get away from maintaining one single open connection, so I had new threads initialize their own new context/connection. A singleton connection pool and Spring JDBC support will solve my issues thanks.